# Client/Server setup only works when on same machine

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking

I have two applications. One is the server app and the other is the client app. The server app listens for connections and then feeds messages to all connected clients.

So far all my testing has been done by running both applications on the same machine, and this is working fine. Now though I am trying to test the server running on one machine and the client running on a different machine.

Each of these machines are within my own home network. That network is behind a router with a firewall. From what I have read, my problem might have to do with port forwarding not setup on my router. Does that sound likely?

Is this something I can fix with just my code? Do I really have to require all my users to manually open the port on their firewalls? I have used plenty of other commercial applications that connect to servers and don't require me to open ports on my firewall. What is different about those applications and mine?

Then again, maybe I am barking up the wrong tree here. Maybe there is some other problem preventing my code from working in this situation?

I can provide any code snippets that might help, but I am unsure as to where to start looking and I don't want to just post my entire solution :)

Thank you in advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with your router. You have to bind to the external address on the server (e.g. 192.168.1.X or INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0)) and connect to the external IP address of that machine using the client.

Comment: My server does do the binding already. It ends up binding to a specific IPv6 address. My client is able to connect 1 of 2 ways; to that specific IPv6 address or the host name of the server machine. Both work when the client application is running on the server machine. But neither work when the application is on a different PC within the same network. I think that that specific IPv6 address might be a local IP though. You think that might be the problem?

Comment: @SnapGames: could you please post what addresses your are binding to?

Comment: Mauve, my code calls getaddrinfo. In this case there are 4 results: fe80::d5b5:6efd:37a8:39e8%11, fe80::38fe:3fae:3f57:fe92%12, 192.168.1.109, and 2001:0:4137:9e76:38fe:3fae:3f57:fe92. Then my code loops through those until it is able to successfully bind to one for listening. Again, in this case it ends up successfully binding to the first and so it ends there.

Comment: I discovered that if I bind to the IPv4 address, then things work. I found this odd because both machines have network devices that support IPv4. Maybe my router does not support IPv4? It is pretty old. Either way, I imagine the proper solution is to bind to all (4 in this case) of the results from getaddrinfo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind to 0.0.0.0 (simplified version) in order to accept connections not coming from the local machine. Have you checked that you don't bind to 127.0.0.1?

When you bind to 0.0.0.0 you actually bind to all current and future addresses of the current host and so will be able to accept connections from everywhere, you can also bind to just the address of one of the network interfaces.

Comment: +1. And his client has to be pointed at the IP of the server.

Comment: Mauve, please see my comment that I added to the original post.

Comment: Ok, so it took me a while to finally understand your answer :) (See my various comments above) I need to call getaddrinfo with NULL as the first parameter. This will then give me 2 results, the "::" for all IPv6 addresses and "0.0.0.0" for all IPv4 addresses. AND I have to bind a socket to each of those, so that clients can connect with either IPv4 or IPv6.